# How to Highlight Rows in excel based on a Formula

Tags: excel, formatting

I'm trying to highlight all rows that have been returned `True` by the following formula in excel: `=$G131=$G132`

In the above, if the details of `G131` are equal to `G132`, then return `True` and Highlight entire row.

Comment: Look into conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the row to be formatted;
- On the ribbon select Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule;
- In the new formatting rule, click Use a formula to determine which cells to format;
- Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula: `=G131=G132`;
- Select the format color;
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>;